# Georeferenced list of international border crossings

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am looking for a georeferenced list of international border crossings for Middle East and South Asia. Is there any reliable source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most requests for spatial data for more than one country, [Open Street Map](https://openstreetmap.org/) is likely to be your friend here. Depending on what [GIS software](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GIS_software) you're using, you can search for features tagged as [`barrier=border_control`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:barrier%3Dborder_control) or [`government=border_control`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:government%3Dborder_control).

If you don't want to use Open Street Map (for example because you don't have time to learn how to use it and are unlikely to need those skills in future) there is a [file of border crossings derived by identifying places where major roads cross national borders](http://worldmap.harvard.edu/data/geonode:border_crossings_phv), although you should note that many border crossings do not carry major roads.